# Data access between parent and child custom-elements

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, polymer

I have a question that I have been unable to find a clear and concise answer to without extra unnecessary calls through Dart and Polymer.

I want to create a parent custom-element that is able to allow it's child objects to access the parents information.

Example:

If I create a container called Student-View that sets up some tabs and pulls the basic information. Then have a child element that is able to access much of the same information through {{firstname}} {{lastname}} etc...

I am not sure the best way to accomplish this, and would prefer if it were all self contained. Or, should I go the angular dart route. Thanks!﻿

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description is pretty vague. Do you mean something like this?

http://jsbin.com/kelub/5/edit

In this case, the parent binds the `student` record to the child element's student property, like so:

`<student-worksheet student="{{student}}"></student-worksheet>`

Comment: Yes. That is what I want to accomplish. All the examples I have looked at do not seem to reference data by an object rather than just strings.